# Руководство по сети в c/c++

Tags: сеть, c, c++, c#

Собственно ищу человеческое руководство по тому как организовать сетевое взаимодействие в c++ c ну и c# (благо они похожи). Может посоветуете книги или статьи?

Comment: Вы уж определитесь с языком, похожи они только в названии, возможности то разные. Да и ОС скажите тогда уж...

Comment: Пока интересуют первые два языка и под винду.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вообще ориентировался на стандартный sys/socket.h.
Еще я использовал материал от глубокоуважаемого К.К. ["Самоучитель игры на Winsock"](http://kpnc.opennet.ru/sock.pdf). Жалко, что под разными операционными системами приходится по-разному выкручиваться. Хотя есть возможность задействовать ту же прекрасную библиотеку [Qt](http://www.qtforum.org/article/9/qt-network-tutorial.html), благо средства сетевого взаимодействия она предоставляет. Да и Qt вполне соответствует духу ООП. Другой вопрос, что C++ + Qt - это уже не совсем C++.

Answer (score 3):

Это ошибочное мнение, что сетевое взаимодействие на языках C++ и C# одинаковое (или похожее).
Несмотря на то, что в основе лежат TCP/UDP/HTTP, реализации в этих языках и соотвественно подходы к программиированию очень сильно отличаются.

- Для C# - нужно изучать [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324).
- Для C++  - Windows Socket и [WinInet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/3w2azyt6(v=VS.90).aspx)

Comment: Я исхожу из того что и там и там пакеты) Отсюда я думаю они точно одинаковы. А можно по обоим темам список хорошей литературы, желательно на русском?

Comment: Почему бы не воспользоваться поиском в ozon.ru? Вот первое, что нашлось: http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5914274/
А по WinInet лучше гуглить, например вот это он нашел: http://www.rsdn.ru/article/inet/wininet.xml

Comment: @Сергей, пакеты одни, но формировать их Вы будете по разному, исходя из языка и надстроек, которые он предоставляет.

Comment: Ну с этим я и не спорю. Хотя мне казалось что раз они родственники то и сеть должна быть одинаково реализована. Ну или хотя бы схожа. Буду знать) Постараюсь изучить материалы, хотя если честно надеялся на какие нибудь более практические книги с примерами что ли.

Comment: C# такой же родственник как и Java для С.
И определитесь между С и С++. Схожий синтаксис это одно, другое дело сам стиль программирования.